# $_GET url parameter after pushstate function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, pushstate

I run a wordpress website. There is a button on the homepage that pushes a new state:

```
<button onclick="javascript:window.history.pushState('test','','?id=123')"
class="modalopen" </button>
```

After I click the button a modal contact form opens that needs to use the id parameter to decide who the email recipient will be in PHP.

I am trying to get the parameter:id from:

```
http://example.com/?id=452
```

Using the $_GET function.

I understand that pushState is client-side and that the URL has not updated server-side. How would I go about updating the url server-side without reloading the page.

I assume it would involve ajax. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge on it.

Alternatively, perhaps there is another way to retrieve the id.

For obtaining the email recipient the contact form uses this code:

```
$post_id = $_GET['id'];
$val = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you share the code for the modal form?

Answer (score 1):

Using history.pushState() changes the referrer that gets used in the HTTP header, this will cause the URL bar to display http://example.com/?id=452, but won't cause the browser to load the url, so you cannot access to $_GET['id'], since the page is not actually requested to the server with that parameter.

If you want to use the id after it is created and without reloading the page you definitely need an ajax call.

Doing it is simpler than what you might think, you can try to do it using jQuery.

a sample call is

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "doSomething.php",
  data: {id:id},
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
     // do something with the data returned by the doSomething.php script
  }
});
```

Google jQuery ajax for more details.
This can be a useful starting point http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

Comment: I have the same problem like the author of this question and would like it if you could explain a bit of what Ajax method that would be best use for this situation. You didn't really explain what each part of your provided Ajax script is used for. I did find a better documentation of what you are talking about. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp as I got this since this looks like methods to me.